# How to get font size from browser settings in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, firefox, browser, font-size

In JavaScript I want to get the user's font-size which is actually set in the browser's appearance settings.

Is it possible to get it in script?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I have tried to find a way to get the font-size which is set in appearance settings and, here is the function which should work on Chrome correctly.

```js
const defaultSize = 16;

function getBrowserFontSize() {
  try {
    const element = document.createElement("button");
    element.style.display = "none";
    element.style.fontSize = "initial";
    document.body.append(element);

    const fontSizeMatch = window
      .getComputedStyle(element)
      .getPropertyValue("font-size")
      .match(/^(\d*\.?\d*)px$/);

    element.remove();

    if (!fontSizeMatch || fontSizeMatch.length < 1) {
      return defaultSize;
    }

    const result = Number(fontSizeMatch[1]);
    return !isNaN(result) ? result : defaultSize;
  } catch (e) {
    console.error(e);
    return defaultSize;
  }
}

console.log(getBrowserFontSize());
```